# Dynamic FROM statement in ACCESS query?

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to write a Passthrough/Union query in ACCESS where the file referred to in the FROM clause changes every month. I am not able to change the name of the file itself so that is not an option.
The file is written monthly (ie. FileXXXX where XXXX is YYMM date). Every month, I want to run the same passthrough query on the previous 6 months files and then join them in a Union query so that I have the data from the most recent 6 months in a single table. The only thing I can think of is to manually change the oldest query date each month in the FROM statement to the newest (ie make FILE2205 into FILE2211 next month) and continue that rotation in perpetuity which doesn't sound like the most effective way to accomplish this. Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Here is what 1 query looks like

```
SELECT DISTINCT
POLICY,
LIMITE
FROM DMHOP2205
WHERE PRMSTE = '21' AND PINFORC = 'Y' AND ORGEFF >= 20220501 AND LIMITE >=300000
```

For this month I want to run the same query on DMHOP2205 through DMHOP2210 and union them all together. Next month I'll want to query DMHOP2206 through DMHOP2211 and so on.

Comment: I'm afraid editing the SQL of the passthrough query is the only option I'm aware of. Create a form with a date control to select the date, format it to YYMM and then use the Replace function to replace the old table name in the SQL property of the query.

Comment: Yes, that is the (only) method. Simple and not at all inefficient.

Comment: What type of file? Can you copy the file? You can name the copy whatever you want.